# Is it possible to define the Order By's sort direction from a selected field value or if statement in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Say for instance I had a query like this:

```
select table1.somedate AS date1, IF(3 = :some_query_parameter, ASC, DESC) AS SortOrder FROM table1 ORDER BY date1 SortOrder;
```

What I'm trying to do is put the value from the SortOrder field into the ORDER BY's ASC or DESC direction so that it is sorted ascending or descending based on the value of the field.

My guess is that this cannot be done, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

Comment: Seems to me this would need an SQL equivalent of Javascript's eval that doesn't exist.

Comment: In your query, `SortOrder` becomes a column identifier, so SQL throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to sort the date in either ASC or DESC order based on a variable, you could try using a CASE statement in the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT table1.somedate AS date1
FROM table1
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN :some_query_parameter = 3 THEN table1.somedate ELSE '1/1/1900' END ASC,
CASE WHEN :some_query_parameter <> 3 THEN table1.somedate ELSE '1/1/1900' END DESC
```

Only one of the ORDER BY clauses above will be used, the other will consistently evaluate to a common value. The value in the ELSE clause must evaluate to the same datatype as table1.somedate.